# Click on fcm notification to go to a particular activity with intent data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a chat application using Firebase.

How to go to a particular chat activity, when clicked on a notification with message data?

Comment: when using firebase, usually the node is basically your chat, so try naming it uniquely and when ever you throw msg the id must be sent along with other json attritbutes and then on click you can easily navigate towards that id.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, you should declare the below intent filter for the activity that needs to be launched when an FCM notification is clicked :

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="NEW_MESSAGE" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

And in your activity that launches when them notification is clicked, you can receive the data from the notification using bundle as below:

```
Bundle extras = notificationIntent.getExtras();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of FCM messages: *Notification* and *Data*.
The simple messages sent from the `Firebase` console are of type *Notification*. This means that when receiving the message in the **background** you can't control which `Activity` to open. BUT when receiving the message in the **foreground** **OR** sending a *Data* message (sent from the `Cloud Functions` or your app server), you can catch the message on `onMessageReceived` and create your own notification.

[image]

link to `Firebase` about receiving messages : [Receive Messages in an Android App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

link to `Firebase` about FCM messages : [About FCM Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

link about starting an `Activity` from a `Notification` : [Start an Activity from a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation)